# How to get geocode by name of the place added by user world wide

Tags: ajax

When you search location using using google map api it gives result  based on given input addresses.This address will only the google map location not the details that user added by add place functionality in google map , for example if the location name is xyz and is located in abc place if you search the xyz in abc then it gives the exact result but if i add a place details in google map api at xyz in abc place and give the place details to "pppp" and search by pppp in abc place it will return nothing.my question is how to get the geocode by the details added by user using add place name.